# Detect user browser language in getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13, i18next

Building a Next.js website and I need to detect the user's browser language in getStaticProps to use in API requests.

I know this can be achieved using i18n, but I don't want the sub-path or the domain to be changed.

Is it possible?